# Call to a member function andWhere() on int in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function actionItemsenbale($organization_id) {

    $items = Item::updateAll(['is_rtm_enable' => SharedConstant::VALUE_ZERO])->andWhere(['organization_id' => $organization_id]);
    return (new ApiResponse)->success(['item' => $items]);
}
```

Comment: i need to update data in table using this model in rest API yii2

Comment: please some one help me

Comment: `$items = Item::where(['organization_id' => $organization_id])->updateAll(['is_rtm_enable' => SharedConstant::VALUE_ZERO]);`

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: its not working @Zain Farooq

Comment: Call to undefined method common\\models\\Item::where()

Answer (score 1):

`updateAll` does not return data. It only returns the count of data that was updated.

After you check if data was updated, do another `find()` with your filters and return that.

```
public function actionItemsenbale($organization_id) {

    $ctr = Item::updateAll(['is_rtm_enable' => SharedConstant::VALUE_ZERO],['organization_id' => $organization_id]);
    if($ctr>0)
        return (new ApiResponse)->success(['items' => Item::find()->where(['organization_id' => $organization_id])->all()]);
    //else
    //    return (new ApiResponse)->failure(['error' => 'nothing enabled']);
}
```

I am only guessing your query as I dont know `ApiResponse` and weather it accepts Item objects or just array like `->asArray()->all()`.

Comment: please show me through coding please @thevikas

Comment: its give me same error Call to a member function andWhere() on int

Comment: merged the where now

Comment: in controller where i use to model

Comment: 'PUT <organization_id:[\w-]+>/itemsenbale' => 'itemsenbale',
     'OPTIONS <organization_id:[\w-]+>/itemsenbale' => 'options',

Comment: this my end point api url

Comment: i used this url in postman  "" http://localhost/api-pos/api/web/v1/items/1e24c46f-b188-11ec-a2f6-0287696325e3/itemsenbale  """

Comment: are u there are u understood

Comment: it seems a bigger question than the time I have.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionItemsenbale($organization_id) {
    $items = Item->find()->where([
        'organization_id' => $organization_id
    ])
    ->all();

    if (count($items) > 0) {
        $item_ids = [];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $item->updateAttributes(['is_rtm_enable' => SharedConstant::VALUE_ZERO]);
            $item_ids[] = $item->id; // Or whatever what you want to send in response
        }
        //If You need, process $item_ids array before send- response 
        return (new ApiResponse)->success(['item' => $item_ids]);
    }
```